# Security Management

Tags: security, open-source

I have/am selected/considering PeerGuardian as my open-source system management application and I am trying to look into SECURITY MANAGEMENT ASPECTS of PeerGuardian. I'm looking into the research areas of reliability & relevant sources of information. Could someone help me out here as this will help in the decision making of securing my hosting services. Any recommendations ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am setting up data hosting for web services and I want to ensure the services are secure so I doing a comparison of an open-source management application (PeerGuardian) against commercial products, but  I have yet to found anything(security aspects) on PeerGuardian, do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: so you're looking for a firewall application? if so for what operating system?

Comment: Erm, I am looking rather into the pros & cons, the efficiency of the PeerGuardian in particular. OS will be Linux.

Comment: isn't it better to look directly at netfilter/iptables firewall rather than something that was used to protect p2p users against sting operations?

Answer (score 3):

PeerGuardian (by default) is for "protecting" p2p users against RIAA/MPAA/etc sting operations, so I am not sure how it will help you in your "system management" needs.

You could use it for loading up generic blacklists of IPs, though there are better apps out there for doing that sort of thing.